# Dropdown option Hide/Show

Tags: jquery

If `Male` selected, then `Actress` option doesn't show up in the dropdown.
If `Female` selected, then `Actor` option doesn't show up in the dropdown.

Html Code

```
<select id="id_sex" name="sex">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Primary Profession</label>

<select id="id_primary_profession" name="primary_profession">
    <option value="">---------</option>

    <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
    <option value="Actress">Actress</option>

</select>
</div>
```

I am trying like this. But it does not work.

Js Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#id_sex").on('change',function(){
               $("select#id_primary_profession").toggle(function(){
                    $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actor']").remove();
                    $("select#id_primary_profession option").eq(2).before($('<option></option>').val("Actress").text("Actress"));
                },
                function(){
                   $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actress']").remove();
                   $("select#id_primary_profession option").eq(2).before($('<option></option>').val("Actor").text("Actor"));
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

I also tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("select#id_sex").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Female"){
        $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actor']").toggle(
            function(){
                $("select#id_primary_profession option").eq(2).before($('<option></option>').val("Actor").text("Actor"));
            },
            function(){
               $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actor']").remove();
            }
        )
    } else if($(this).val() == "Male"){
        $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actress']").toggle(
            function(){
                $("select#id_primary_profession option").eq(2).before($('<option></option>').val("Actress").text("Actress"));
            },
            function(){
               $("select#id_primary_profession option[value='Actress']").remove();
            }
        )
    }
});
```

});

Can you please help? thanks

Comment: I think when you remove one `option` there's no `eq(2)` option, only 0 and 1.

Comment: Toggle function is only for click. You can use if else.

Comment: See my answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the simple way:

Please notice the data attributes in select options.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vY4X7/)

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var profession = $('#id_primary_profession');
    $('#id_sex').change(function(){
        //grab the data value from the selected option
        var optData = $(this).find(':selected').data('pfoption');
        //remove previously selected option, which is either actor or actress
        //and append the new selection based value
        profession.find('option:eq(1)').remove().end().append(
            $('<option/>').val(optData).text(optData)
        );
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="id_sex" name="sex">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="Male" data-pfoption="Actor">Male</option>
    <option value="Female" data-pfoption="Actress">Female</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Primary Profession</label>

    <select id="id_primary_profession" name="primary_profession">
        <option value="">---------</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I"ve just added `actor` and `actress` in dropdown. And using your code but it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/vY4X7/1/. thanks

Comment: @no_freedom, first of all, please see the code I've posted closely. You can at least do that while we take our time to help you! the 2nd dropdown is an empty dropdown with an empty option unlike the one in your fiddle. I have updated the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vY4X7/4/ to my code above and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Using your HTML, try this in jQuery. I've tested it and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#id_sex").on('change',function(){
           var sex = $(this).val();
           if(sex == 'Male'){
               $('#id_primary_profession').find('option').each(function(){
                   if ($(this).val() == 'Actress'){
                       $(this).remove(); //Hard remove, could also hide
                   }
               });
           }
           else if (sex == 'Female'){
               $('#id_primary_profession').find('option').each(function(){
                   if ($(this).val() == 'Actor'){
                       $(this).remove(); //Hard remove, could also hide
                   }
               });
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/vY4X7/3/. There are some problems. Its deleting actor/actress values if you click 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code but should work or perhaps a little tweak.

```
$(document).on('change','#id_sex',function(e){
   if($(this).val() == 'Male'){
      $('#id_primary_profession option:first').remove();
      // or  $('#id_primary_profession').html('<option value="Actor">Actor</option>'); 
  }
  else{
     $('#id_primary_profession option:second').remove();
     // or  $('#id_primary_profession').html('<option value="Actress">Actress</option>'); 
  }
});
```